# Basic square function done with array & malloc

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *squares(int max_val) {
    int *result = malloc(max_val * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= max_val; i++) {
        result[i-1] = i*i;
    }
    return(result);
}

int main() {
    int *sq = squares(10);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", sq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Basically take's an integer and returns a integer array of its squares. (Above works)

How would I do this without malloc or pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int[] squares(int max_val) {
    int result[max_val];
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= max_val; i++) {
        result[i-1] = i*i;
    }
    return(result);
}

int main() {
    int sq[] = squares(10);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", sq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Above errors because of the function call. Is this possible? Or do we have to do it with pointers?

Comment: The second version returns a pointer to an array on the stack which goes out of scope when the function call ends. Aka undefined behavior. you could make `int result[max_val]` global or static in yje `squares()` fn.

Comment: You allocate on the stack in main

Comment: `int[] squares` is a syntax error. You cannot return arrays in C

Comment: If you want to pass array-like things between functions, you have to use pointers--that's how C works. Or else make your arrays global :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this.. ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void squares(int values[], int max_val) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= max_val; i++) {
        values[i - 1] = i * i;
    }
}

int main() {
    int sq[10];
    squares(sq, 10);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", sq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int[] squares(int max_val) {
    int result[max_val];
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= max_val; i++) {
        result[i-1] = i*i;
    }
    return(result);
}
```

is not valid C:

```
a.c:3:4: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
 int[] squares(int max_val)
```

It should be

```
int *squares(int max_val) {
    ...
}
```

Putting that aside, your second `squares` returns a pointer to a local array.
This array ceases to exist once `squares` ends it's execution, so you are
returning an pointer that become invalid the moment it returns.

Also

```
int sq[] = squares(10);
```

is invalid C as well

```
a.c:9:13: error: invalid initializer
  int sq[] = squares(10);
             ^~~~~~~
```

you cannot assign a function value to an array. The correct
version is

```
int *sq = squares(10);
```

So, if you don't want `squares` to allocate memory with `malloc` for the result, then you can
either allocate the memory in `main` or create an array in main and pass it to
`squares`:

```
int squares(int *result, int max_val) {
    if(result == NULL || max_val <= 0)
        return 0;

    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= max_val; i++) {
        result[i-1] = i*i;
    }

    return 1;
}

// version 1
int main() {
    int *sq = malloc(10 * sizeof *sq);

    // NEVER forget to check the return value of malloc
    if(sq == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    squares(sq, 10);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", sq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(sq); // NEVER forget to free

    return 0;
}

// version 2
int main() {
    int sq[10];

    squares(sq, sizeof sq / sizeof sq[0]);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", sq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would the downvoter please care to explain what I did wrong so that I can fix my post?